# how to get two toggle hide/show buttons to take up the same space in a body?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry for the poorly worded title. I have two buttons that show/hide pictures. The first button shows 4 images, the second button shows 1 image. If the first button is toggled off (hidden), and the second button is toggled on (showing) the one image appears below where the first 4 images would be if they were showing. How do I get it so that it takes up the same space where those four images would go so it's not sitting at the bottom of the page?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YrJPdp

**Note when you click the second button while the first one is toggled off, the image is all the way at the bottom of the page.**

Here is my js:

```
// button 1
document.getElementById("ate-multistage").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("atl-axial").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("atm-multiturn").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("tank-bottom-valve").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("ball-valve").style.visibility = 'hidden';

function pic1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("ate-multistage");

  if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    x.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
function pic2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("atl-axial");

  if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    x.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
function pic3() {
  var x = document.getElementById("atm-multiturn");

  if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    x.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
function pic4() {
  var x = document.getElementById("tank-bottom-valve");

  if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    x.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}

//button 2
function pic5() {
  var x = document.getElementById("ball-valve");

  if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    x.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `visibility` `visible/hidden`, you can try to use `display` `block/none`. `display` will not occupy the space for hidden elements.

Comment: @PhaniKumarM you should post your answer below instead of commenting it here. Anyway, yeah that will do the job.

Comment: This works! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: none` and `display: block` instead of `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible`. That ensures that the hidden elements do not take up any space when rendered.

> The visibility CSS property can show or hide an element without affecting the layout of a document (i.e., space is created for elements regardless of whether they are visible or not). - From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)

Here's the updated codepen:

https://codepen.io/Nisargshah02/pen/oGaxao?editors=0010

Comment: That simple, huh? Thanks so much!! :)